# Idle bash script until CTRL+c event is logged

Tags: linux, bash, sleep, ctrl

I have a bash script which does some work, which is done fairly quick.
It should then idle until the user decides to terminate it, followed by some clean-up code.

This is why I trap the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> event with the following code:

```
control_c()
{
  cleanup
  exit 0
}

trap control_c SIGINT
```

But as my script is done quite quickly I never get to purposely terminate it, so it never gets to *trap the CTRL+c* and run the clean-up code.

I figured I could implement an endless `do while` loop, with `sleep` at the end of the script, but I assume there is a better solution.

How can I idle a script in bash, expecting the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> event?

Comment: BTW, why not just put that in a generic EXIT trap? `trap cleanup 0` and you're no longer depending on details of *how* you exit, as long as it isn't something like SIGKILL that can't be trapped at all.

Comment: I don't think that that's possible in my case. The script enables a bunch of `iptables` rules which should only be in effective until the user decides it is no longer required.

Comment: I'm not saying you don't wait for ctrl+c or enter or whatever, I'm just saying you use an EXIT trap rather than a SIGINT trap -- that way it still fires for exits that aren't SIGINT-based.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming you're connected to a TTY:

```
# idle waiting for abort from user
read -r -d '' _ </dev/tty
```

Comment: Is directing /dev/tty necessary ?

Comment: I just tried this solution with and without `< /dev/tty` and the result seems to be identical.

Comment: @123, it might be necessary, depending on what else the script is doing. Read rules from stidn, and run it as `yourscript <firewall-rules`, for instance, and then the `read` needs `</dev/tty`. If environment hasn't been specified (as it hadn't), I'm going to assume the worst (or make cases where I *must* assume something, like availability of a TTY at all, explicit).

Comment: @boolean.is.null, ...see above; the `</dev/tty` is a robustness improvement, letting this be used even if the script is taking input from elsewhere.

Comment: what if you aren't connected to any TTY but just locally what's the solution then? my script waits with this code but it doesn't do the rest of the script afterwards

Comment: Oh, god bless u. You saved my day!

Comment: @OZZIE I used Brent Bradburn's answer in my shell script and it worked as expected, the script continued. You could try that.

Comment: I have a script with this solution at end, and another script that uses `dialog` that calls it as a job, the script with `dialog` gets crazy, like someone is constantly pressing Esc key!

Answer (score 5):

The following will wait for Ctrl-C, then continue running:

```
( trap exit SIGINT ; read -r -d '' _ </dev/tty ) ## wait for Ctrl-C
echo script still running...
```

Comment: I haven't tested all scenarios, but this may be `bash` specific.  In a GNU makefile, it may require `SHELL = bash`.

Answer (score 1):

I had problem with `read -r -d '' _ </dev/tty`, I placed it in a script to prevent it from exiting and killing jobs. I have another script that uses `dialog` and calls the first one as a job, when the script reaches `read -r -d '' _ </dev/tty` the parent script dialog have a very weird behavior, like someone is constantly pressing the `Esc` key, this makes the dialog try to quit.

What I recommend is to use `sleep` you can sleep for a long time like 999 days `sleep 999d` and if you need for sure for it to never stop you wan put it in a while loop.

Comment: Some systems also support `sleep infinity` that sleeps for a *very* long time